# Postgres log in issues from CMD

Tags: postgresql

I forgot passw for postgres DB so I have removed postgreSQL from system and I reinstalled it again with  new passw. Now I can access postgres from  SQL shell as postgres user by entering new passw and it works.

However when Im trying to open postgres from CMD, by executing `psql postgres` Im prompted to enter passw for user Pet. If I provide dbname and username in CMD `psql postgres postgres` then it doesnt attempt to log me in as Pet, it just accept my passw and log me in as postgres user. My question is why does it prompt me to log as Pet if I dont provide username? I havent set up Pet as user for Postgres DB, so it shouldnt even be asking for Pet passw which I have never set up, should it?

Answer (score 1):

By doing:

`psql postgres`

you are telling `psql` to connect to the `postgres` database as the system user, in this case `Pet`. To accomplish what you want, do:

`psql -d postgres -U postgres`

where `-d` specifies the database you want to connect to and `-U` specified the database user you wish to connect as.

The details can be found in the docs here:

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/app-psql.html